# How can I activate a pane from the main page url entry?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to be able to load the main page to the site where the "active" pane can be chosen in the URL when the page is loaded.  For example http://www.somepage.com/#advancedSearch  Is that possible?

Here is my current setup:

```
<div class="well">
  <div class="row-fluid">

    <div class="span12">

      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="simpleSearch" class="tab-pane active">
         <div class="span8">
          <h4><%= I18n.t("brand.welcome_message") %></h4> <h5>(Other searches are listed below.)</h5>
          <%= render_aspace_partial :partial => "simple_search" %>
         </div>
            <div class="span4">
              <%= render_aspace_partial :partial => "browse_side" %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="advancedSearch" class="tab-pane">
         <div class="span8">
          <h4><%= I18n.t("brand.welcome_message_adv") %></h4> <h5>(Other searches are listed below.)</h5>
          <%= render_aspace_partial :partial => "advanced_search" %>
         </div>
            <div class="span4">
              <%= render_aspace_partial :partial => "browse_side" %>
              <%= render_aspace_partial :partial => "advanced_help_side" %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="cartographicSearch" class="tab-pane">
         <div class="span8">
          <h4><%= I18n.t("brand.welcome_message_map") %></h4> <h5>(Other searches are listed below.)</h5>
          <%= render_aspace_partial :partial => "cartographic_search" %>
         </div>
         <div class="span4">
          <%= render_aspace_partial :partial => "cartographic_side" %>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div id="operationSearch" class="tab-pane">
         <div class="span8">
          <h4><%= I18n.t("brand.welcome_message_ops") %></h4> <h5>(Other searches are listed below.)</h5>
          <%= render_aspace_partial :partial => "operation_search" %>
         </div>
         <div class="span4">

         </div>
        </div>
        <div id="cdecSearch" class="tab-pane">
         <div class="span8">
          <h4><%= I18n.t("brand.welcome_message_cdec") %></h4> <h5>(Other searches are listed below.)</h5>
          <%= render_aspace_partial :partial => "cdec_search" %>
         </div>
         <div class="span4">

         </div>
        </div>
        <div id="thesaSearch" class="tab-pane">
         <div class="span8">
          <h4><%= I18n.t("brand.welcome_message_thesa") %></h4> <h5>(Other searches are listed below.)</h5>
          <%= render_aspace_partial :partial => "thesa_search" %>
         </div>
         <div class="span4">

         </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    <div class="span12">
      <ul class="search-switcher">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#simpleSearch" data-toggle="tab" style="font-size:110%" onclick="window.scrollTo(0, 165);"><%= I18n.t("actions.hide_advanced_search") %></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#advancedSearch" data-toggle="tab" style="font-size:110%" onclick="window.scrollTo(0, 165);"><%= I18n.t("actions.show_advanced_search") %></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <hr />
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#cartographicSearch" data-toggle="tab" onclick="window.scrollTo(0, 165);"><%= I18n.t("actions.show_map_search") %></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#operationSearch" data-toggle="tab" onclick="window.scrollTo(0, 165);"><%= I18n.t("actions.show_operation_search") %></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#cdecSearch" data-toggle="tab" onclick="window.scrollTo(0, 165);"><%= I18n.t("actions.show_cdec_search") %></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#thesaSearch" data-toggle="tab" onclick="window.scrollTo(0, 165);"><%= I18n.t("actions.show_thesa_search") %></a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <%# recent_posts %>
    </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, possible. Google "browser pushState". We're not going to write code for you, but you can try something and ask for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have setup a javascript code or jQuery plugin that does all the logic of *tabbing* already. So, all you have to do is to trigger a `click` event on the correct tab:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if(hash) {
        $('.search-switcher a[href="'+hash+'"]').click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you can add some basic JavaScript to your page to handle this for you.

Assuming you are familiar with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(
  function(){
    the_anchor = window.location.hash || '#someOtherAnchor'; // in your example URL, this would return the string '#advancedSearch'
    $(the_anchor).addClass('active');
  }
);
```

The above does not account for another tab already having an `active` class already. It's just to give you an idea on how, with client-side JavaScript, you can react to the "anchor" (i.e. `#advancedSearch`) in your URL.

Comment: I think this works well.  I added a small edit (under review) to provide a default anchor if no hash is present. Then, no need to have an active tab in the HTML, as JS will always yield one.

Comment: Separate comment on purpose -- one thing this doesn't address is the actual link to activate the tab. That class would need to be updated as well. So, close but not quite. But definitely a foundation for the OP to get started.

Comment: And thats all the response was intended to be ... just a starting point (OP doesn't note how the links are accessed, etc., so I went with a generic way to act on the 'anchor' in the URL). BTW - I accidentally rejected the edits! My bad! Going to recreate the code change now though!